# Set conversation typing indicator from backend

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible for a backend service (`deno` in my case) to set the [Conversations Typing Indicator](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/typing-indicator#typing-indicator-send)?

I have a use-case where I have a process that is sending messages to the conversation, and I want to set the typing indicator while the process is generating the response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as this feature only seems to be available in the browser Javascript client.  As an alternative, just send a message that says "Generating the response". Unless it is going to take minutes to complete the user will know you are working on sending them a response.

You might be able to wire up a something where the agent triggers the typing indicator within the browser using some kind of callback. For example, your server API sends a message to the client in the browser using SignalR. Then SignalR running in the browser triggers the typing indicator. This would need to run in the browser and not on a server - unless you can figure out how to get the Javascript client to run in the server (which likely isn't possible/practical).

Comment: in theory, if it can be done in the browser, it can be done server side. 

I did some digging through the client-side source and it looks like it's making a request to `https://aim.us1.twilio.com/v1/Instances/IS8.../Typing`using an undocumented npm package called [twilsock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilsock).   I assume it's a websocket connection, but the url protocol indicates otherwise.  Going to see if I can standup a project and capture a network request.